# What is the opposite of case-sensitive and does "case-insensitively" exist?

Tags: adverbs, antonyms

I thought it was "case-insensitive" but there are very few sources. If it's correct, what is it's adverb? As a non-native english speaker i would say it's "case-insensitively" but that sounds odd and i haven't found any sources but my [own post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378491/284240):

*This will compare case insensitively:*

```
bool equals = x.Equals(y , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yes it is case- insensitive. check this : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23046/is-case-sensitively-a-word

Comment: @Nikita: that's about "case-sensitively" not "case-insensitive" or "case-insensitively".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Case-insensitive** is indeed the correct antonym. That's the normal tech term. Evidently, it can be used with or without the hyphen.

Example:

> To cause a case-sensitive comparison of nonbinary strings to be case insensitive, use COLLATE to name a **case-insensitive collation**.

Or:

> This example shows that VERSION() returns a string that has a case-insensitive collation, so **comparisons are case insensitive**:

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

As for the adverb, to me *case-insensitively* sound a bit awkward, so I would prefer **in a case-insensitive manner**:

> You can configure the property value comparisons in query search conditions to be performed **in a case-insensitive manner**.

(http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc406.htm)

Or, you can simply do without an adverb or adverbial phrase and write something like:

> This will perform **a case-insensitive comparison**.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance guys. I will accept this answer. Thanks also for the tip to by-pass the suspect adverb with "perform a case-insensitive comparison".

Comment: No problem, Tim, glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite would be *case-insensitive* and even Wikipedia say's so.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity

But, I must agree that case-insensitively sounds odd and I have personally never used it and have never heard anyone else doing so either.

Another thing I found is that the site Word Hippo says it did not find an opposite term to to *case-sensitive*.
http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/case-sensitive.html

So, in the end it comes down to how you want to use it. You can always say, Not Case sensitive.

Comment: You link takes me to a Wikipedia article with the warning "This article needs additional citations for verification."  The claim that the opposite of *case-sensitive* is *case-insensitive* is unsupported.  A statement that the google's searches are "case-insensitive" is footnoted, but the link goes to a page that does not use the term.  Both you and Wikipedia may be right, but Wikipedia is usually just a starting point.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but you could clarify that Word Hippo doesn't "say" anything other than it failed to find a match for your query.

Comment: @deadrat You need citations? I am just showing that the word exisits. Nothing else. And, as you said wiki is just the starting point. Isn't that exactly what i have done and shown?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop I take your point on existence, and as well on what is sometimes an obsession around here about citations.  But the question was two-fold and includes the query about the term that's the opposite of "case-sensitive."  My warning about Wikipedia stands.  And, but the way, I am not the downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

[Case-sensitive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/case-sensitive) is an adjective for stating that the comparison will recognize (or be sensitive to) character capitalization.

Since the antonym of *sensitive* is *insensitive*, it makes sense to keep the object (case) unchanged and reverse the behavior to insensitive. (No supported reference other than common-sense interpretation :P.)

Comment: Common sense turns out to be a weak guide.  For instance, it might lead you to smoke around containers marked "inflammable."  By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @deadrat sometimes it is easier to understand the origin using common sense.. Being a programmer,I can guarantee "this doesn't always helps!! " :P for instance String is common word for a thread but for a programmer its a "sequence of characters"..!!!